# Compiling external library as set of used classes in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, compilation

is it possible in Netbeans to configure java compilation process in such a way, that whole **external library** would not be just copied into resulting jar file, but compiler will **include only used classes** (and their dependencies) or chunks of used code as "inline methods"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about using NetBeans for this. It sounds like you're looking for [ProGuard:](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)

> ProGuard is a free Java class file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator, and preverifier. It detects and removes unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes. It optimizes bytecode and removes unused instructions.

This tool is commonly used to minimize [APK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_application_package) size but its use is certainly not limited to Android apps.